Sampling irrational numbers
I'm sorry that my unclear statement has caused some misunderstanding. This edit was just to stop misunderstanding, Keep Closed.
I don't know if there is another software with a better fit for this project than MMA, or maybe I should ask questions on the math channel.

Context:
Mathematically, the probability  of  randomly  sampling  an  irrational  number  from the  number  axis  equal  to  1. Except  for like "Pi,E", Mma  cannot  produce  irrational  numbers. (* --- I read a quiz: what is the probability of obtaining a rational number of points from the number axis? My expectation is to simulate the process, just like Binomial Distribution: drawing a black(irrational) and white(rational) ball.Generate irrational numbers just because I don t know how to quantify the number of black and white balls so it’s not necessary. --- *)
Question: Can  a  computer  or  Mathematica  sample  irrational  numbers? (* --- Simulation process of random sampling, Generating irrational numbers is just one way I choose. --- *)
My test: Both trigonometric and exponential functions were excluded, I ended choose  the  EulerGamma to construct sample space. But something wrong, EulerGamma give the result unequal to 0.
Clear["`*"]
Pr[n_] := Module[{},
  SeedRandom[123];
  realNumbers = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
  (*MachineNumberQ/@realNumbers//Union*)
  
  rationalNumbers = Rationalize[realNumbers, .1];
  
  gammaFunc = Factorial[rationalNumbers](*~Echo~
  "Total sample collection"*);
  (Length[Select[gammaFunc, IntegerQ]]/Length[gammaFunc]) // N(*~Echo~
  "rational number probability";*)];
  
listPr = Table[Pr[n], {n, 1, 10^5, 10^4}]
ListPlot[listPr]



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Rationalize[realNumbers, .1] rounds about 20% of realNumbers to 0 or 1, which is what you see in the plot. OTOH, Rationalize[realNumbers, 0] would round about 0% of them to 0/1. The gamma function seems a red herring. What really is being computed is how many of the floats returned by RandomReal get rounded to an integer by Rationalize.

@ Michael E2 is right.

Here is a way to get as many irrational numbers between [0,1] as your computer has memory to hold:
Table[n Pi - Floor[n Pi], {n, max}]

Note, you can approximate these with finite-decimal representations, but that is not necessary.  These are bona fide irrational numbers, just in a representation that some are unfamiliar with.
To "take a sample," simply choose an $n$ as large as you like and generate an irrational number in [0,1].
You can easily computationally determine properties, e.g., if
(5 Pi - Floor[5 Pi]) + (9 Pi - Floor[9 Pi]) 

is irrational.
You can easily compute using such irrational numbers.  You can compute $\pi - \pi$ and never need to convert to a decimal representation.
If you're claiming you cannot sample irrationals, well you cannot sample integers either, or positive integers, or rationals, ...
Nothing special about irrational here (countable, or not)!

If this is an actual answer to the question, then someone needs to clarify what we mean by "sample". I assumed that "sample" meant something like "draw from a uniform distribution of the irrationals". If the OP was simply asking to generate some number of irrationals, then sure, that's easy. But the numbers your solution generates come from a small subset of all possible irrational numbers in [0,1].

Your construction Table[n Pi - Floor[n Pi], {n, max}] produces a finite set of transcendental numbers of the certain sort. Is this set representative (see Irrational measure)?

@lericr:  ALL finite samples taken from an infinite set "come from a 'small subset' of all possible irrational numbers in [0,1]."  SEE?

Note that the product of a rational and irrational number is irrational.
To sample irrational numbers from the interval (0,1) you could e.g. sample a rational number from the interval (0,1/Sqrt[2]) and multiply by Sqrt[2]:
(Rationalize[RandomReal[{0, 1} ]/Sqrt[2], 10^-16 ])  Sqrt[2]



This is a countable set. The set of all the irrational numbers belonging $[0,1]$ is not countable. In particular, transcendental numbers do not belong to your set. Therefore, such a sample could not be called representative.

Have I just completely misunderstood the question? How is this solution a sample of all irrationals in the range? Aren't you excluding the majority of irrationals?

(Oh gee.). As said above:  ANY FINITE SET TAKEN BY A FINITE MACHINE/ALGORITHM MUST BE A SUBSET OF THE FULL INFINITE SET.  (SAME WITH INTEGERS, WITH RATIONALS, WITH COMPLEXES, WITH ...).  YES YES YES... ALL THESE MUST EXCLUDE "THE MAJORITY" OF IRRATIONALS (OR INTEGERS, OR RATIONALS, OR COMPLEXES, OR...).  CLEAR????

yes, @DavidG.Stork, that is clear. Finite << Countably Infinite << Uncountably Infinite. I do indeed understand this. I'm sincerely sorry that the language I've used has been sloppy.

I was never trying to make the point that your algorithm didn't work because it couldn't produce an uncountably infinite set of samples. I was trying to make two points: (1) your algorithm was biased, and (2) there might actually be theoretical reasons beyond computational limitations that make an unbiased sampler impossible.

As for (1) my concept of "bias" may not be sufficiently rigorous and therefore (1) is pointless. Feel free to provide the mathematical proofs to enlighten me. As for (2) feel free to ignore. I was just musing.

You provide no evidence my algorithm is biased.  I don't have time to prove it, but run this:  list = Table[n \[Pi] - Floor[n \[Pi]], {n, 100000}]; Histogram[list]. Sure looks unbiased to me (in a distribution sense).

@DavidG.Stork If you really want to continue the conversation, then do so in the chat room that has been created.
